# Retrieve ring tokens via thrift or CQL api

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to retrieve token-to-node assignment information (aka the ring state) via thrift or CQL api. I am looking for output similar to what `nodetool ring` command returns? I need that to optimize a client application a bit so that it goes directly to the node that contains the requested data hereby saving one network hop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thrift interface has the method `describe_ring` that gives you back this information.

In CQL this information is in the `system.peers` table:

```
select * from system.peers;
```